# .htaccess rewrite subdirectories to null

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I want the browser location bar to show http://dir/ when I really am in http://dir/subdir/subdir.

How do I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow you to enter `http://yourdomain.com/dir/` into your address bar and get the content that would normally be displayed for `http://yourdomain.com/dir/subdir/subdir/`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/dir /dir/subdir/subdir
```

Is this what you want? If not, please clarify.